# Puppeteer how to click a button when id, name not available

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

This may be a simple one, but I am not getting how to click a button in Puppeteer if id, name of button not available.

Consider below html code.

```
<button data-bb-handler="success" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Answer</button>
```

How I can click the Answer button in Puppeteer .

I tried below code, it does not work.

```
page.click('#Answer');
page.click('button[data-bb-handler="success"]');
```

Please let me know how I can click the button in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work based on your HTML:

```
await page.click('button[data-bb-handler="success"]');
```

or try to click with the `$eval` function.

```
await page.$eval('button[data-bb-handler="success"]', button => button.click());
```

but this is untrusted event, read more [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#q-whats-the-difference-between-a-trusted-and-untrusted-input-event).

also, you may need to wait for the element before click:

```
await page.waitForSelector('button[data-bb-handler="success"]', {visible: true});
await page.click('button[data-bb-handler="success"]');
// or
await page.$eval('button[data-bb-handler="success"]', button => button.click());
```

Comment: Your solution works fine. I just looked into trusted and un-trusted events. If I go with un-trusted events, is there any problem like click would not take effect randomly .., please clarify.

Comment: No, it only means that the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched. So if you are developing automation tests and want to be sure that each action is like real users do -  you should use trusted event, but if you are just scraping or doing something that does not require to do like real users do -  use a `$eval` or `evaluate` function. Also, keep in mind that some websites can block untrusted events. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for explanation.